# Slow performant query in Arangodb

Tags: arangodb

Hypothetically I have two collections.

`users (document type)`and 
`relations (edge type)`

Relations collection has two attributes `{user1, user2}` and is indexed combined.

My following query is extremely slow:

`FOR r in relations filter (r.user1 == 'xyz' && r.user2 == 'abc') || (r.user1 == 'abc' && r.user2 == 'xyz')
RETURN r`

With 800 users and 5000 relationship it takes 35 seconds.

Comment: Can you provide the index definition here?

Comment: Indexing wasn't proper. After the proper indexing it'f performant

Comment: You should post your solution as answer and accept it.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal : It would be nice if you could post your solution as CoDEmanX suggested

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal can you also mark your own answer as 'accepted'? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't create the indexes properly before. I recreated the indexes again and then the performance was improved.